# Trying to create zip file on the fly but items are not added

Tags: php, zip, popen

I am trying to zip up some files and send it the user to download.
The zipfile is sent as intended but none of the text files are added to the archive.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I have tried relative and absolute file paths.

Also, as a secondary question: If this code is correct my dev environment is a WAMP set up and my live environment is a LAMP set up - will this code work on both?

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download1.zip"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
ob_clean();
flush();
$fp = popen('zip -0 -j -q -r - C:\xampp\htdocs\test\f\1.txt C:\xampp\htdocs\test\f\2.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {
echo fread($fp, 8192);
ob_flush();
flush();
}
pclose($fp);
```

Comment: On linux I believe you should use exec not popen. Also, shouldn't you be writing not reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st filename in the zip command is the name of the zip file to create, the following files are the files you want added to the achieve. Seems like simply fudging in a fake zip file does the trick:

$fp = popen('zip -0 -j -q -r -  download1.zip test.txt test2.txt', 'r');

Comment: Strange that works in my LAMP environment, maybe it has something to do with WAMP.